# Is an $n$-connected space a homotopy colimit of $n$-connected spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A pointed, $n$-connected space $X$ admits a CW structure using just $n$-connected spheres, so $X$ is an *iterated* homotopy colimit of $n$-connected spheres (i.e. you start with spheres and keep taking colimits, and eventually get whatever you want). On the other hand, if we take a pointed simplicial set $X_\bullet$ representing a given homotopy type $X$, the identity $X \simeq |X_\bullet|$ expresses $X$ as a *bona fide*, 1-step homotopy colimit of wedge powers of $S^0$ (i.e. it gives a single diagram, whose values are wedge sums of $S^0$'s, whose homotopy colimit is $X$).

**Question:** Let $X$ be an $n$-connected pointed space. Then is $X$ a homotopy colimit of wedges of $n$-connected spheres?

I think it's reasonable to hope the answer is *yes* -- possibly after assuming everything is simply-connected.

**Notes:**

- Any homotopy colimit can be consolidated into a geometric realization at the cost of introducing some more wedges. So it's equivalent to ask whether $X$ is the geometric realization of a simplicial object whose values are wedges of $n$-connected spheres.
- One approach I've considered is to take an $n$-reduced simplicial model of $X$, and maybe use this to express $X$ as a colimit of $\Delta[m] / sk_n \Delta[m]$'s (these skeleta are always wedges of spheres). But I'm not sure how to ensure that the resulting geometric realization is really a homotopy colimit.
- Clearly if $X$ is an $n$-fold suspension space the answer is *yes*.
- I'd be happy to know the answer "up to retract" -- i.e. to know whether every $n$-connected $X$ is a retract of a homotopy colimit of $n$-connected spheres.
- I'm also happy to assume that $X$ is finite.
- Everything here is pointed -- all maps / homotopies should be pointed, and all homotopy colimits are meant in the pointed sense.

Comment: Note that by iterated hocolim you can build any $n$-connected space out of copies of $S^{n+1}$ (because a point is an empty hocolim and suspension of $X$ is a hocolim of $X$ and points). So you might even ask whether every $n$-connected space is a hocolim of wedges of $S^{n+1}$. This is the case for $n=-1$, as you observe, and I believe it is also the case for $n=0$ by letting $X$ be $BG$ for a simplicial group $G$ that is levelwise free: $B$ commutes with hocolim and $B$ of a free group is a wedge of circles.

Comment: There is a canonical map $\text{Bar}(S^n,\Omega^n\Sigma^n,\Omega^nX)\to X$ which is a weak equivalence if $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected.  This exhibits $X$ as the geometric realisation of a simplicial space in which each layer has the form $S^n\wedge T$ for some $T$, but $T$ is not discrete so this does not do exactly what you ask for.  Perhaps you can replace $T$ by its singular complex and then diagonalise?

Comment: @NeilStrickland That sounds perfect -- I think the diagonalization should work. And the convergence of this bar complex to $X$ is related to the May recognition theorem for $n$-fold loop spaces, right?

Comment: @NeilStrickland Could you clarify how $\Omega^n \Sigma^n$ acts on $S^n$? I thought this requires $S^n$ to be framed.

Comment: @TimCampion I think the result Neil is using is called "Nonabelian Poincare duality".

Comment: @TimCampion Do you know if the same can be done for colimit diagrams? I mean, does a colimit diagram of $n-$connected spaces have a simplicial resolution made of $n-$connected spheres such that it is levelwise a colimit diagram? I think this is true for $n = 0, 1$ thanks to simplicial sets and simplicial (free) groups, but it doesn't seem to me that Neil's answer can make this work. Have you ever thought about this?